# Unsupported operation camel and Ethereum

Tags: apache-camel, ethereum

I am trying to use apache camel with ethereum. I want to retrieve the balance for an account but I got an error that the operation is unsupported.

Where can I view the supported operations ?

Below is the error message

Unsupported operation ETH_GET_BALANCE

Answer (score 0):

For the component you can have a look here: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/web3j-component.html

While in the producer you have the possible operation:
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-web3j/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/web3j/Web3jProducer.java

We need to add the operations supported in the docs. Can you please open a JIRA issue for this here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CAMEL/issues/CAMEL-15238?filter=allopenissues